# stuck with sqlite transaction using java

Tags: java, sqlite, transactions

```
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
    try {
        for (String q : query) {
            if (q != null && !q.equals("")) {
                  stmt.executeUpdate(q);
            }
        }
        stmt.execute("COMMIT");
        stmt.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
        stmt.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Details Successfully Added.",
         "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         System.out.println("Rollback:\n " ex.getMessage());
         stmt.execute("ROLLBACK");
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,ex.getMessage(),
         "Exception Occured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

i have written above code to insert multiple records using transaction, but when i execute it, it sometimes gives me `could not commit no transaction is running` and sometimes `could not rollback no transaction is active` while the records are successfully getting inserted.

as i am new to sqlite and java, i am not getting what is the actual issue here, please anyone guide me or help me to make it run..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you not call,

```
stmt.getConnection().commit()
```

instead of

```
stmt.execute("COMMIT");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you start the transaction, that's also what the two error messages indicate. Try

```
stmt.execute("BEGIN");
```

to start a transaction in line 3.

Comment: thanks for answer, but `stmt.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);` this line already doing that i guess..

Comment: I think that depends on the implementation of your driver. Autocommit is afaik not defined in the sqlite specs.

Comment: i think that when we set `autoCommit false` then we need to implicitly call the commit action to save data else it will not save the data..